# Nginx Issue with Subdomains

Tags: nginx

I'm having an issue with my nginx. I have a subdomain mapped to a folder and it loads the index but nothing else. Anyone see the issue with my congfig? I don't know if there is another congfig, but this is what was set up for us.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 768;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# nginx-naxsi config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
##

#include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

##
# nginx-passenger config
##
# Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
##

#passenger_root /usr;
#passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Here is the congig file for the subdomain with the issue:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name streaming.thecanonhouse.com;

    location / {
            root /srv/opentok/learning-opentok-web/web/;
            index index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
    }

    location @php {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what do you see, does index.php get downloaded? What if php named location is removed, are requests served from that? What's running on port 8080 on the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of the server block from official nginx website

```
    server {
  # Replace this port with the right one for your requirements
  listen 80 default_server;  #could also be 1.2.3.4:80

  # Multiple hostnames separated by spaces.  Replace these as well.
  server_name star.yourdomain.com *.yourdomain.com; # Alternately: _

  root /PATH/TO/WEBROOT;

  error_page 404 errors/404.html;
  access_log logs/star.yourdomain.com.access.log;

  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  # static file 404's aren't logged and expires header is set to maximum age
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    # By all means use a different server for the fcgi processes if you need to
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:YOURFCGIPORTHERE;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
  }
```

Comment: Pulled the root out of the location command and it looks like everything is loading.