# nginx/sites-available issue with subdomain from a different host

Tags: tensorflow, nginx, flask

I have a domain on bluehost. I am trying to subdomain a flask app on Digital Ocean. Everything works great up until this point with the nginx/sites-available/webApp:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name therapist.vrifyhealth.com www.therapist.vrifyhealth.com;

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/root/webApp/webApp.sock;
}
}
```

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801845/nginx-issue-with-subdomains) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60566525/how-do-nginx-sites-available-work-with-subdomains) and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) fails to help because I'm trying to run a flask application. Is there a way to run a flask app with server blocks? I have my BH subdomain pointing to the IP of this droplet. Could I just deploy the site as a standalone IP? Any advice?

--I'm running through the root because my user on the site was having issues with running tensorflow--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have forward the new ip to the correct address with the subdomain appended! Then once the hosting provider completes pushing the ip to the new address, this should work!